# Dividing up an index params into multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of records that I have displayed on an index page. (they are displayed in a table form). Because there are a number of them I am trying to divide them up to about 30 records per page. I've created a search params functionality with the index displayed beneath it.

The problem that I am having is that I am having trouble getting more than one page to render on my list. As of right now I have about 150 records. However I only have one page listed with only 30 records on it and am not able to sort through them.  Would anybody have any idea what I could be missing?

Here is the segment in my code where this gets addresssed.

```
  def search_params
    default_index_params.merge(params.fetch(:record_collection, {})).with_indifferent_access
  end

  def default_index_params
    {
      per: 30,
      page: 1,
      sort_by: "created_at",
      sort_direction: "desc",
      customer_id: 0 
    }
  end
```

In my view, I do have a little bit of coffee-script that plays a role in the table itself. I don't know if it is the root of my problem, but I have it here as well.

```
:coffeescript
  $('#record_table').dataTable
    aaSorting: [[1, 'asc']]
    bPaginate: false
    bFilter: false,
    aoColumns:[null, null, null, null, null, { bSortable: false }, null, { bSortable: false }]
```

My record collection is used for defining the params, i don't think that it is useful for this problem. (but could certainly post if needed)

Thanks in advance to anybody who is able to help figure out what is going on with this.

Comment: look into pagination. Probably the most popular and easiest to use is `will_paginate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass paging: true and pageLength: 30 in coffescript, and just remove page: 1,per: 30 from default_index_params method. So your coffeescript will look like this:

```
:coffeescript
      $('#record_table').dataTable
        aaSorting: [[1, 'asc']]
        paging: true
        pageLength: 30
        bFilter: false,
        aoColumns:[null, null, null, null, null, { bSortable: false }, null, { bSortable: false }]
```

your default_index_params will looks like this:

```
def default_index_params
    {
      sort_by: "created_at",
      sort_direction: "desc",
      customer_id: 0 
    }
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. I took what you offered, however it unfortunately did not fix the entire problem. What it did was split the pages into 3, and defaulted to only 25 entries.   I really have not been able to figure out why it is only displaying 25 results.

Comment: The only thing that I have been able to do so far that kinda fixes the problem is to change the `per: 30` to `per: 500` and that displays all the 150 of the records split between a specific number of windows.  However i don't want to use that as a solution as there could one day be far more than 500 records.  (I really hope all of that makes a little sense, and I do greatly appreciate your willingness to help out a bit. )

Comment: pageLength: 30 will give you 30 records per page and you have 150 records so it will paginate all records with 30 per page records, I think you are missing something check this https://datatables.net/